# Where can I find example or template security testing contracts?

Tags: penetration-test, legal

I'm a lawyer interested in information security, and am collecting templates and examples of security testing agreements to compare. What are some publicly available examples, or nuggets of wisdom from your own practices?

***Why I'm asking***

I'm looking to compare forms of agreements and then distill their common ingredients. With that, I intend to put together a draft template of my own, or at least publish some thoughts on the subject. I'm not being lazy or doing this for a client project.

***lmgtfy***

I have already Googled the question. (One cannot survive modern law school without expert Googling.) I'm looking for a bit deeper knowledge here.

***Is this question on-topic?***

I think this question is on-topic because it's about the business of information security -- but if people disagree, I'd appreciate a pointer to a more appropriate place. Quoting directly from [this community's "on-topic" help article](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Laws** - Answers on laws, regulations and licencing should not be taken as legally binding - we're security professionals so deal with legal issues, but this site is not a law site.

To me, that implies it's fine to ask questions about law as long as you use common sense in interpreting the answers.

Comment: It took me about 15 seconds to type "example of security testing contract" in google. http://www.pwcrack.com/penetration_contract.shtml Hope this helps

Comment: Hi there. I highly doubt that these agreements are publicly available at all. Many times, they contain highly privileged information about client systems and company secrets. I would imagine that reading cyber-law journals would be more helpful than an answer here :)

Comment: Thanks. Templates would be fine--I'm not interested in people's secrets.

Comment: unfortunately, you've asked for what amounts to be a legal resource

Comment: As a formerly practicing attorney who's now a practitioner of infosec (Well, okay, like 65% general IT, 35% infosec stuff), let me suggest (1) as with many types of contract templates using Google to find a number of sample documents or templates and using them as guides for your own judgment to create your own template will often be a good investment of time. At least...

Comment: ...in fields like this where contracts of adhesion (and ones almost as boilerplate) are never used. And (2) formulating a "testing" engagement is more like creating a multi-party partnership that setting up a one-owner LLC: you may be able to find sample docs & templates, but you also need to be up to speed (or get up to speed) on at least the most commonly relevant substantive issues in such relationships. So that you'll be able to decide whether a the specific language of a document covers the specific things a client in a specific engagement really should have it cover.

Comment: Well, I certainly didn't expect this much grief from asking a question about the **business of information security**. Thanks @AlexeyVesnin.  
  
This similar question didn't get jumped on: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63866/penetration-testings-terms-of-agreement-template?rq=1  
  
What I'm actually trying to do is collect templates so I can compare them, figure out what the common ingredients are, and then come up with, and publish as open source, a template or other useful resource.  

I'll reword the question, but after that I'll go elsewhere if the hostility continues...

Comment: @Ansel I'm sorry that you feel jumped on and feel hostility, but we are actually trying to help you. If you note in the other question (which I just closed), the one answer doesn't point to contracts and the other says "consult a lawyer". No one wanted to touch it. Legal resources are jurisdictionally dependant, and as others mentioned, tend to include sensitive data. You mention that you did a search. Did you find anything? A better question *for this site* might be to ask if some sources you found were typical for pentesting.